# WebLogic Server 12c cant log in localhost Exception weblogic.nodemanager.NMConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, nodemanager

I use a Oracle WebLogic Server 12c and when I start it on Eclipse it shows this error, it does'nt allow me to log in localhost neither when I try to access it 
from another computer in a different domain, in the log appears that the server is not reacheable.

This is the exception that appears in Eclipse.

```
This Exception occurred at Wed Nov 13 08:11:07 CET 2019.
weblogic.nodemanager.NMConnectException: Connection refused: connect. Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at localhost/127.0.0.1:5556.
Problem invoking WLST - Traceback (innermost last):
  File "C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\bin\scripts_manejados\StartBT.wlst", line 1, in ?
  File "<iostream>", line 111, in nmConnect
  File "<iostream>", line 552, in raiseWLSTException
WLSTException: Error occurred while performing nmConnect : Cannot connect to Node Manager. : Connection refused: connect. Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at localhost/127.0.0.1:5545.
```

This is my nodemanager properties:

```
#Tue Nov 12 09:45:58 CET 2019
#Node manager properties
#Fri Jun 24 14:55:43 CEST 2016
DomainsFile=C\:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\Oracle_Home\\user_projects\\domains\\base_domain\\nodemanager\\nodemanager.domains
LogLimit=0
PropertiesVersion=12.1.3
AuthenticationEnabled=true
NodeManagerHome=C\:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\Oracle_Home\\user_projects\\domains\\base_domain\\nodemanager
JavaHome=C\:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_75
LogLevel=INFO
DomainsFileEnabled=true
StartScriptName=startWebLogic.cmd
ListenAddress=localhost
NativeVersionEnabled=true
ListenPort=5540
LogToStderr=true
SecureListener=false
LogCount=1
StopScriptEnabled=false
QuitEnabled=false
LogAppend=true
StateCheckInterval=500
CrashRecoveryEnabled=false
StartScriptEnabled=true
LogFile=C\:\\Oracle\\Middleware\\Oracle_Home\\user_projects\\domains\\base_domain\\nodemanager\\nodemanager.log
LogFormatter=weblogic.nodemanager.server.LogFormatter
ListenBacklog=50
```

And this is my StartBt script file, used to start the server and specify some preferences:

```
nmConnect('weblogic','AXLWL20040','localhost','5521','base_domain','C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain','plain')

nmStart('AdminServer')

nmDisconnect()
```

I want to make it accesible, not only for local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly configure the ports. Your NodeManager listen on port 5540

```
ListenPort=5540
```

You try to connect to 5545

```
WLSTException:..Could not connect to NodeManager. Check that it is running at localhost/127.0.0.1:5545
```

Comment: Yes, it was that and it happend in the script file an others too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

```
nmConnect('weblogic','AXLWL20040','localhost',**'5521'**,'base_domain','C:/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain','plain')
```

Port should listen to 5545.